# Line start/end space in draw.io doesn't work?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I wanted to add an spacing between the line start or end and the connected object. For example

```
OBJECT ----> OBJECT
```

instead of

```
OBJECT------>OBJECT
```

There is a feature for the line but it seems not to change anything:
[image]

Do I misunderstand this feature or is it a "bug"?

Answer (score 2):

Line start/end spacing only works with floating connections (Blue shape outline when you connect).

Source - [draw.io Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/drawio/P-FdmLQPhCk/Ojed6uECBwAJ)